# Reading json file in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file in the following format:

`{"Day": [{"NameofDay": "Beginning of year"}]}`

If `NameofDay` has some text in it other than None, then I have to print that text. Else, I should not do anything.

I tried with the following code but I am not sure on how to add condition to it.

This is the first time I am using javascript. Any guidance would be really very helpful to me.

```
  function drawMessage(){
    var tt =  $.ajax({
       url: "findDay.json",
       dataType: "json",
       async: false
       });

    var jsonData = tt.responseJSON;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done inside the $.ajax sucess callback method and it will be asynchronous.

```
$.ajax({
       url: "findDay.json",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (data) {
        //Do stuff with the JSON data
        if(data.Day[0].NameofDay != 'None'){ //This condition be dependent on your requirement.
           var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        }
        }
       });
```

Comment: It's not asynchronous if you use `async: false`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `for` loop to loop over the contents in the array and check if the property value is not equal to `None` as you mentioned.

Here is the code for the same-

```
  function drawMessage() {
      var tt = $.ajax({
          url: "findDay.json",
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function(jsonData){
                      for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Day.length; i++)
                         if (jsonData.Day[i].NameofDay != "None")
                             console.log(jsonData.Day[i].NameofDay)

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
  }
```